# $\text{Ind}^G_B \eta_B$ is an irreducible representation of $G$ if $\eta^2 \neq 1$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $F$ be a finite field of odd characteristic, and let $G = SL_2 (F)= \Bigg\lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
    a       & b  \\
    c       & d 
\end{pmatrix} : a, b, c, d \in F, ad-bc =1 \Bigg\rbrace$. Let $B$ be the subgroup of $G$ which consists of matrices $\begin{pmatrix}
    a       & b  \\
    c       & d 
\end{pmatrix} \in G$ with $c=0$. Let $\eta: F^\times \to \mathbb{C}^\times$ be a homomorphism and define $\eta_B : B \to \mathbb{C}^\times $ by $\eta_B \big( \begin{pmatrix}
    a       & b  \\
    0       & d 
\end{pmatrix} \big) = \eta (a)$. Prove:

1. $\eta_B$ is a representation of B
2. $\Bigg\lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
       1       & 0  \\
       0       & 1 
   \end{pmatrix} ,  \begin{pmatrix}
       0     & 1  \\
       -1    & 0 
   \end{pmatrix} \Bigg\rbrace$ is a set of representatives for the double cosets $B \setminus G / B $.
3. $\text{Ind}^G_B  \eta_B$ is an irreducible representation of $G$ if $\eta^2 \neq 1$

I've shown 1. and 2., but for 3. I have read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570906/induced-representation-of-g-sl-2-by-chi-w-is-irreducible-if-w2-neq-1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194397/computing-character-of-a-representation-and-irreduciblity) which are very similar but I am not sure if I understand the argumentation provided in the answers. Thus I wanted to know if anyone could provide a more explicit answer in the sense where it is more clear how we are using Mackeys irreducibility criteria and the Frobenius Reciprocity.

Comment: You can prove (2) using elementary row operation. (3) is proved in one of the link you provided https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194397/computing-character-of-a-representation-and-irreduciblity